# Using JSON parse on object to controller results in lists containing one null item instead of null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I know the title of this question is a little confusing. The problem I have is I'm passing an object to my controller after using JSON parse. The object contains lists and these lists get passed into the controller having a count of 1 item which is null, instead of the entire property being null.

Model:

```
public class QboModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 @{ var qboModel = new QboModel { Id = 0, Customers = null, Invoices = null }; }
 <a href="#" onclick="refresh('new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(qboModel)')">Refresh</a>
```

Script:

```
function refresh(qboModel) {
    $.post(url, { qboModel: JSON.parse(qboModel) }, function(data) {
        // Do stuff
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Refresh(QboModel qboModel)
{
    // qboModel.Id = 0
    // qboModel.Customers = Count = 1, [0] null
    // qboModel.Invoices = Count = 1, [0] null
}
```

I hope I've explained that correctly. Basically I cannot do:

```
if (qboModel.Customers == null) return;
```

Instead I would have to do something like:

```
foreach(var customer in qboModel.Customers) {
    if (customer == null) return;
}
```

Comment: What does the json you are parsing looks like?

Comment: Have you tried with NewtonSoft JSON? https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: @Luiso Comes in as a stringified object so: "[{"Id":0,"Customers":null,"Invoices":null}]"